# Ubuntu 20.04 boots into initramfs

Tags: ubuntu

I am using ubuntu 20.04 OS installed in my system, I get into the following problem while booting my system. While booting it boots into `initramfs', can anyone help me to resolve this issue?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks, the following method, helped me to resolve the issue.

type

> `fsck /dev/sda1`

then type

> `yes`

Once all the process completed type -

> `reboot`

if reboot did not work type

> `exit`

Comment: I can't type anything there, all characters turn to the hidden format

Comment: @amiralisabzehparvar try typing `stty sane` (`/usr/bin/stty sane`) or `reset` (`/usr/bin/reset`) and hit Enter.

Comment: If you have encrypted LVM, then check if you see the backing device is decrypted and active `dmsetup table`.
If you don't see your `_crypt` device there, then load it up manually `cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sda3 sda3decrypted`.
Then scan for LVM bits `lvm pvscan`, `lvm vgscan`, `lvm lvscan`, `lvm lvchange -ay`.
And then, depending on your filesystem, scan FS on your LV for errors, for ext2/3/4 FS `e2fsck -y /dev/vgubuntu/root`.
Finally, type `exit` and hit Enter. You should boot as normal.

Comment: for me, exit and reboot do not apply anything

Comment: I have the same issue, but when typing yes, the PC still shows me y for half an hour. How long time should it take?

Comment: @Redhwan because that ran the program `yes` which just types `y` forever. It was supposed to be a "yes" in reply to a question that `fsck` asks you, but these instructions did not account for that not happening.